# $ export CXX g++ error :bash: export: `g++': not a valid identifier

Tags: linux, cygwin

Getting error in executing CXX command with g++ in Cygwin64  to run the netcdf library. How to run this command in Cygwin. How to run NetCDF library in Cygwin64.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a Cygwin problem. You're simply missing the equal sign to make this an assignment:

```
export CXX=g++
```